# Java Program find string length from user input

Tags: java, string

```
public class Strings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word1 = sc.next();
        System.out.println(word1.length());
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

So i want to make a very simple program that takes in a user string and returns the length, but the program does not even run. I am using eclipse. Any tips?

Comment: How does it "not run"? Any error messages?

Comment: Put that in a try catch..!! If you are not getting any error message..!!

Answer (score 3):

Your program works fine.

Are you forgetting to type something into the console? It might appear to not be running but it actually is.

ALSO: If you are new to java/programming I would suggest using Netbeans over Eclipse. Netbeans offers a bit more support, although it is less flexible (something you shouldn't need to worry about right now).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your are providing an input to calculate the length of word.

This is working fine if you providing an input, it is better to change your code as follows:

```
public class Strings {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your word: \n");
    String word1 = sc.next();
    System.out.println(word1.length());
    sc.close();
  }
}
```